# how to "rowise merge" pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to merge 2 DataFrames, such that in the new DataFrame first row = row 1 from df1 and the second row is the first row from df2 etc.

```
A=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,5], 'B': [7,9,11]}, index = ['bs','ss','db'])
B=pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,4,6], 'B': [8,10,12]}, index = ['bs','ss','db'])
```

Note that row and column labels are exactly the same and both dataframes have the same dimension.

So the desired output should look like

```
      A    B
bs_a  1    7
bs_b  2    8
ss_a  3    9
ss_b  4    10
db_a  5    11
db_b  6    12
```

Im not familiar with pandas merge, and after looking in the documentation i still dont know how to do this

Answer (score 8):

You can do `concat` with `keys` , the merge the multiple index

```
s=pd.concat([A,B],keys=['a','b']).sort_index(level=1)
s.index=s.index.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format) 
s
Out[225]: 
      A   B
bs_a  1   7
bs_b  2   8
db_a  5  11
db_b  6  12
ss_a  3   9
ss_b  4  10
```

Comment: @user11638654u yw:-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

you could `rename` your dataframe's index and then `append` one to the other

```py
df = A.rename('{}_a'.format).append(B.rename('{}_b'.format)).sort_index()
```

This gives

```py
        A   B
bs_a    1   7
bs_b    2   8
db_a    5   11
db_b    6   12
ss_a    3   9
ss_b    4   10
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
A.reset_index(inplace=True)
B.reset_index(inplace=True)

A['index']=A['index']+'_a'
B['index']=B['index']+'_b'

A.set_index("index",inplace=True)
B.set_index("index",inplace=True)

final_df = pd.concat([A,B]).sort_values(['A'],ascending=[True])
final_df.index.name=''
```

```
        A   B
bs_a    1   7
bs_b    2   8
ss_a    3   9
ss_b    4   10
db_a    5   11
db_b    6   12
```